# Adding custom option at form field type 'entity'

Tags: symfony, entity

In my form builder, using an entity choice field I can retrieve the contents of an entity by:

> $builder->add('manufacturer', 'entity', array(
>               'class' => 'Manufacturer'....

Everything works fine and the selectbox is rendered correctly at the view. However, I would like to add an extra option at the selectbox called "Add new" (it will not be mapped to an entity), which would result at a select box with options of manufacturers plus one at the end with Add new. What is the best Symfony2 way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $new_choice = new ChoiceView(null, 'value', 'label');

    $view->children['manufacturer']->vars['choices'][] = $new_choice;
}
```